# How do you iterate over entries in a zip file in random order in Java?

Tags: java

I'm working on a machine learning project and I have 10,000 training files stored in a zip. I want to train my model on each file in the zip file, and I heard it is preferable to randomize the order of your training data if you train over your full dataset multiple times. This project is done in Java.

So I was wondering if it is possible to iterate over entries in a `ZipFile` in a random order in Java? Here is the API I referred to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html

Comment: Yes, it is possible, using a [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) number generator and the [`getEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html). What particular problem are you having using those?

Comment: oops, well the original issue was that the names of the files aren't something nice like "case1", "case2", ... "caseX" etc. but I realized I can go through the data on one pass and collect all the file names then randomly index to a name each time. Just curious if I could get some iterator object which could go through it randomly

Comment: Correct. Except that you want each entry exactly one time, so it would be easier to just add all entry names to a `List`, then [`shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-java.util.Random-) the list and iterate it.

Comment: Gotcha, great that works for me. Feel free to submit your comment as an answer; I'd be happy to approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the zip file using [`zipFile.entries()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries--) and add the zip entries to an [`ArrayList<ZipEntry>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Randomize that list by calling [`Collections.shuffle(list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-).

You can now simply iterate the randomized list and call [`zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream-java.util.zip.ZipEntry-).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following as a starting point:

```
        ZipFile f = new ZipFile("path_to_file");
        Enumeration<ZipEntry> entries = (Enumeration<ZipEntry>) f.entries();
        List<ZipEntry> entryList = new ArrayList<ZipEntry>();
        while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
            ZipEntry enrty = entries.nextElement();
            entryList.add(enrty);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(entryList);
        for(ZipEntry e:entryList){
            System.out.println(e.getName());
        }
```